# How do I define a 3D line that does not leave the horizontal plane?

Tags: vectors

If I want to define the line y=2x when discussing 3D lines this is actually a plane. We should be able to turn it into a line with cartesian equation x=2y=z/0 but that would give us something undefined. How do you resolve that problem?

Comment: In general, you can't determine a single line with something to the effect of $f(x,y, z) = 0$. I would go with your approach or parametrics.

Answer (score 0):

The general rule-of-thumb is that in $n$-dimensional space $\Bbb R^n$, every equation you add cuts the dimension by $1$.

- In the plane, $y=x$ gives a line. A system of $2$ equations like $x=y$ and $x=3$ determines a point.
- In $\Bbb R^3$, $y=x$ gives a plane. The system $x=y$ and $y=z$ defines a line, and something like $x=y$, $y=z$, and $z=3$ gives just a point.
- In $7$-dimensional space, $y=x$ gives a $6$-dimensional hyperplane, you need $6$ equations to describe a line, etc.

All you need to do here is write $x=2y$ and $z=0$. I suppose with some elbow grease you could force this into one equation like $(x-2y)^2+z^2=0$, but I'm not sure this is an improvement.